# english textual date expression cakephp find queries

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

let's say that I have a database table called `users` in a cakephp application which contains a bunch of users and in that table I have a field called `date` which contains the registration date of each user. Let's say that I wanna make a find query to get all the users registered last month for example. Something like:

```
$last_month_users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.date' => 'last month'
    )
));
```

Something like this doesn't work. Any idea how I would do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mysql, you're looking to add in your statement:

```
WHERE MONTH(User.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I believe you can do this in cakePHP by doing the following:

```
$last_month_users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'MONTH(User.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'
    )
));
```

Comment: Are you using mysql?  Have you turned on debug input to see what mysql query it tries to produce for that find statement?

Comment: Yes I have debug on and the query that it tries to execute is this:
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`date`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE MONTH(`User`.`date`) = 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'
Which returns and empty array

Comment: Looks like it's putting quotes around MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) when it shouldn't.  Try conditions => array('MONTH(User.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)') instead

Comment: Yes! This works!, thank you, but what is the meaning of CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH? Is there a doc for that where I can see more explanations on those functions?

Comment: It's just taking today's date and subtracting a month from it.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: It would be good if you'd update your answer with the correct code, so that people don't have to search the comments. ps, the behavior is correct, when using the `key => value` style escaping is applied automatically, see for example http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions